# Надо ли закавычивать слова?

Tags: кавычки

> Для западного человека это все обозначается одним словом – "Восток",
>   не важно, идет ли речь об арабах, индийцах, китайцах или монголах.
>   Такая искусственная конструкция создает всему, что подразумевается под
>   названием "Восток" при всем его очевидном многообразии, образ
>   безликости, не обладающей никакой индивидуальностью, кроме того факта,
>   что он – "не-Запад".

Надо ли закавычивать слова "Восток" и "не-Запад"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для западного человека это все обозначается одним словом – "Восток", не важно, идет ли речь об арабах, индийцах, китайцах или монголах. Такая искусственная конструкция создает всему, что подразумевается под названием "Восток" при всем его очевидном многообразии, образ безликости, не обладающей никакой индивидуальностью, кроме того факта, что он не-Запад.

Если бы не было интонационного тире после "одним словом" то кавычки были бы необходимы, а в случае с тире необязательно. В конце предложение закавычивать не-Запад не надо.

Comment: А можно объяснить, почему? Разве все три слова не на "равных правах", то есть все кавычить или все - нет?